# ionic2 ion-list too much padding

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2

Too much padding on the right side of my ion list.

[image]

I was able to decrease padding on left side with

```
padding: 0 0 0 0 !important;
```

But cannot find any way to affect the right side.

```
    <ion-list class="wrapping-list">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let listItem of list; let i = index" no-padding row-no-padding (click)="seeListItem(i)" (long-press)="longPressListItem(i)" (swipe-left)="swipeLeftItem(i)">
        <ion-avatar item-left>
            <img width="30px" height="30px" src="{{listItem.thumbnail}}" />
        </ion-avatar>
        <h2>{{ listItem.name }} </h2>
        <p>{{ listItem.summary }} </p>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Here is everything I tried with CSS:

```
.wrapping-list .item-content, .wrapping-list .item {
overflow: initial;
white-space: initial;

padding: 0 0 0 0 !important;
}

.no-padding {
    padding: 0 0 0 0 !important;
}

.item-complex .item-content {
  padding: 0 0 0 0 !important;
}

.item-right
{
    padding: 0 0 0 0 !important;
    margin: 0 0 0 0 !important;
}
```

Other formatting questions:

1. How do I get rid of the lines between items?
2. Why is the line only under text and not picture?
3. How can I make the second line of text (grey text) two lines with wrapping?

Comment: All the the classes your'e trying(according to the css above) to target is not present in the html markup except "no-padding"

Comment: You should run your app in browser then inspect element and try to find which element have padding.

Answer (score 1):

To make it work I had to add this to app.scss:

```
.item-md.item-block .item-inner {
    padding: 0 0 0 0 !important;
}

.label-md {
    margin: 6px 8px 0px 0;
}
```

and create a custom css file for the page with this in it:

```
.item-md [item-left] {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 4;
}

.item-md [item-right] {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0;
}
```

When I moved the stuff in app.scss to the other css file it didn't work for some reason.